# Navigation menu for all pages in HTML

Tags: html, css, menu

I have two HTML documents that will be linked to the same site. How do I create a navigation menu that I will only need to edit once, for its changes to be applied to all HTML documents that menu is on?

I'm a beginner to HTML and have learnt the basics, but could you please help?

This is the menu code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="games.html">Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="apps.html">Apps</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In plain HTML no. Using JavaScript or something on the server such as PHP yes.

Comment: The only way to do it with HTML would be to include the navigation HTML into the other pages as an iFrame(not reccomended). A better thing to do would be to code it in PHP and then include the navigation that way.

Comment: What APAD1 suggests is your best option.  A simple include of headers/footers will make it so you can edit once and change for all pages.  Framed sites are...well...I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to include some HTML file to another.
With HTML less 5-th version you can't do this without javascript. The best solution to use jQuery if you don't want use PHP/Java/.NET solutions. But don't forget that you will need use local server (for example, Apache).

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $.get("menu.html", function(data) {
    $("#menu").html(data);
  });
});
```

**menu.html:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="games.html">Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="apps.html">Apps</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

JQuery: [jquery.com](http://jquery.com/)

Docs: [api.jquery.com/html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Did you mean to say "script.js" instead of "script.html"?

Comment: I wouldn't use this solution.  If javascript is disabled it wont work.  Plus it just seems like overkill.

Comment: James Korden, I am write: "The best solution to use jQuery if you don't want use PHP/Java/.NET solutions."

Comment: JDS404, yes - "script.js", sorry)

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to do this with just plain HTML.

Few Options :

Javascript - Using javascript you could append the navigation to each page.

PHP - Using PHP would be easiest and you could process your navigation as an include to your code.

In my opinion you should use php.. JavaScript is way overkill for this particular situation. What I typically do it create a series of php files that form the structure for my websites.

A Simple structure would be

- head.php
- index.php

create a php file named head.php, you can do this using notepad, notepad++, netbeans etc..

**head.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<!-- NAVIGATION SECTION HERE -->
<div class="nav">
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">First link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**index.php or your other pages**

```
<?php include "head.php"; ?>

<div>
content of html page
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you notice at the top of index.php you see an include statement. This will add the head.php contents to any page that you call this include from. Since your navigation section is located in head.php, your navigation will be uniform throughout all of your pages.

For this to work, please make sure that your host allows you to use php.